# Multiple options select with chosen-js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to create a multiple option selector using [chosen-js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

[This](https://codepen.io/nriddiford/pen/KJNWVo) codepen, shows what I'm trying and how it's different from what I'm expecting (e.g. [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/99Dkm/1/)). The below snippets highlight the relevant html and js. I'm nesting the `<select>` tags within a bootstrap4 `container` and `col-12`:

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100vh;">
        <div class="col-12 mt-4 mb-4 h-100" id="test">
            <div class="mt-4 header">
                <p>Choose some games!</p>
            </div>
            <select id="mySelectId" data-placeholder="Add skills..." class="chosen-select" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="Chess">Chess</option>
                <option value="Monopoly">Monopoly</option>
                <option value="Cards">Cards</option>
                <option value="Cluedo">Cluedo</option>
                <option value="Snap">Snap</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**choose.js**

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "50%"});
```

While it is working to some extent - [see pen](https://codepen.io/nriddiford/pen/KJNWVo) - the behaviour is not as expected:

- Clicking on the form automatically selects and enters an option
- After clicking in the form, the option list is full width (overlapping any entered text) and disappears quickly after first appearing - hopefully this is apparent in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/nriddiford/pen/KJNWVo)

**Am I doing something obviously wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your fiddle saw a style

```
 .center_v a, h1, p, ul {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

In that style, the transform property was the reason for your problem. try to add your own class rather than giving styles directly to tags like p ul.. etc